# java getDisposition returns null on emails with attachments

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

SO i'm making a mail client for a homework assignment and one of the requirements is to handle incoming attachments. The first thing I want to do is just show if an email even has an attachment or not. I have a bunch of AWT lists that are side by side for From, Subject, Size, Date, Attachment.

For testing purposes, if the disposition returns null, i just put an x in the attachmentList. If its inline, it puts an i and for attachments it should show the filename. However, even on emails where there are attachments and looking at the headers in gmail webmail, which shows the content disposition as attachment (all lower case), the getDisposition of the email still returns null. I don't get why its not returning ATTACHMENT or attachment or something besides null. Here is the relevant code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                Address[] froms = messages[i].getFrom();
                String email = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();
                fromList.add(email);
                subjectList.add(messages[i].getSubject());
                sizeList.add("" + messages[i].getSize());
                dateList.add(messages[i].getReceivedDate().toString());
                String disposition = messages[i].getDisposition();
                System.out.println("Disposition is " + disposition + ".");
                if (disposition == null) {
                    attachmentList.add("x");
                }
                else if ("INLINE".equalsIgnoreCase(disposition)) {
                    attachmentList.add("i");
                }
                else if ("ATTACHMENT".equalsIgnoreCase(disposition)) {
                    String fileName = messages[i].getFileName();
                    if (fileName != null) {
                        attachmentList.add("attachment " + fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
```

You'll notice that it prints "the disposition is..." which is another testing code and it always prints either null or INLINE. The particular email i'm looking at is about 700k and contains 2 attachments.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the raw MIME text of the message and make sure the Content-Disposition header is set as you expect.

Turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and examine the protocol trace in the debug output.

Are you using IMAP to read the message?  If so, the IMAP server parses the message and returns the "disposition" information in the IMAP protocol message.  The IMAP server may not be parsing the message correctly or may not be returning the disposition information correctly.

Comment: Im not really sure by what you mean by looking at the raw MIME text. I checked the headers in gmail and found the disposition heading and it was set to attachment but my mail app still returns null. For inline, it returns inline. I am using IMAP in my program and the imap server i'm using is gmail.

Comment: In the Gmail web interface there's a down arrow on the right that gives you more options including "Show Original", which will show you the raw MIME text.  Look for the Content-Disposition header for the message part you're concerned about.  Also, post the debug output here so we can see what the server is returning when you access that part.

Comment: I'm going to try and attach the debug info. The info is from the folder that contains one message that has an attachment.

Comment: Ok i cant seem to find out how to attach files so here is one line from the debug that clearly shows there is an attachment. * 1 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE ((("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "7BIT" 18 1 NIL NIL NIL)("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "7BIT" 39 1 NIL NIL NIL) "ALTERNATIVE" ("BOUNDARY" "047d7b3a8c4eb7ee2204e131558f") NIL NIL)("APPLICATION" "MSWORD" ("NAME" "assignment_4.doc") NIL NIL "BASE64" 72868 NIL ("ATTACHMENT" ("FILENAME" "assignment_4.doc")) NIL) "MIXED" ("BOUNDARY" "047d7b3a8c4eb7ee2504e1315591") NIL NIL))

Comment: Also when I go into the message in gmail and "show original", I can see the disposition header which is this: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="assignment_4.doc"

Comment: Yes, it looks like the body part corresponding to the assignment_4.doc attachment should have a disposition of "attachment".  If that's not working, I can't explain why.  What version of JavaMail are you using?  Feel free to contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com to debug this further.

Comment: I emailed you. Also sometimes when trying to display the content, i get a basee64 message, it looks almost like when you try to print an object that doesnt have a toString() method, othertimes nothing shows. I will research that encoding thing because I dont believe its related or difficult to solve.

Comment: Hi, @Richard Chase Did you get this problem fixed? I have the same like you. When I forward a mail contains attachment via the mail app on iOS. The javamail will return null disposition.